# How to display the search item in the ui-select menu in Vue

Tags: vue.js, ui-select

Is there any way I can display my search item to the `ui-select` menu in vue? Like for instance, if the user typed in the search field, and like for example in an  on-blur event or while typing, it will display the item to the `ui-select` menu:

[image]

So, for example in the picture above, word "testings" is displayed in the highlighted field. What I've done so far is below, but can't reach my goal.

```
<ui-select 
    v-model="groupName"
    has-search
    @blur="hello"
    @query-change="checkEvent"
></ui-select>
```

**METHOD:**

```
checkEvent(val) {
    this.groupName = val;
 //but this one is not displayed in my field, like it's remain on the search field.
}
```

Is there any way I can do that?

Comment: What's the v-model of the ui-select?

Comment: @FewFlyBy This one - `v-model="groupName"`

Comment: Is groupName an array?

Comment: @FewFlyBy No, it's just a string.

Comment: can you share the link of the ui-select component?

Comment: @FewFlyBy Here you [go](https://josephuspaye.github.io/Keen-UI/#/ui-select).

Comment: even blur event isnt working?

Comment: try adding this.$forceUpdate(); after this.groupName = val;

Comment: @FewFlyBy It's still not working. If I have to use, `@blur` event, how would I do it correctly?

Comment: can you try this.$set(this, 'groupName', val) inside checkEvent?

Comment: @FewFlyBy Still cannot display it, but `this.groupName` has already a value, (updated everytime I type a character).

Comment: Weird, I got it working with just those https://codepen.io/anon/pen/rKLjbr

Comment: @FewFlyBy Thanks for this. Maybe you can put it as an answer, will check this out ;)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So I made it work using the latest CDN of keen-ui and Vue.

Here's the pen: https://codepen.io/anon/pen/rKLjbr

```
<div id="app">
    <ui-select 
    has-search
    label="Favourite colours"
    placeholder="Select some colours"
    v-model="item"
    :options="colours"
    @query-change="checkEvent"
    ></ui-select>
</div>

<script>
new Vue({
    el: '#app',
    data() {
        return {
            item: '',
            colours: ['red', 'violet']
        }
    },
    methods: {
        checkEvent (val) {
            console.log(val)
            this.item = val // this will automatically update and be outputted in the highlighted field in your screenshot.
        }
    }
});
</script>
```